# Why am I getting this error, left of 'method' must have class/struct/union?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am building three classes, Maze, MazeRow, and MazePoints, to hold a maze structures and I am having trouble with setting up my vector for the MazeRows.The below code is from my Maze class code. I have included my header file for MazeRow. I am getting 3 errors each where i am calling a vector method. Also myMazeRows is a private member variable of Maze Class

```
//Maze Header File    
#include "MazeRow.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
namespace MazeSolver
{

class Maze
    {
    public:
        Maze(int rows, int columns);
        MazeRow *      getRow(int row);
            private:
                    vector<MazeRow> myMazeRows();
```

---

```
 //Maze Implementation File
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "Maze.h"
 #include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace MazeSolver;


  Maze::Maze(int rows, int columns)
{
     //Recieving the Compile Error  (C2228)
      myMazeRows.resize(rows);

     //Initializing Each Row
     for(int i=0; i< rows;i++) //Recieving the Compile Error  ( C2228 )
           myMazeRows.push_back(MazeRow(i,columns));
}

MazeRow*       Maze::getRow(int row) 
{
    //Recieving the Compile Error (C2228)
    return &myMazeRows.at(row); 
}
```

---

```
//Maze Row Header File
class MazeRow
   {

   public:
       MazeRow(int rowNum, vector<MazePoint>);
       MazeRow(int rowNum, int mazPoints);
```

Comment: Which lines demonstrate the error? What is the *actual* error message (copy and paste)? Also please show the actual definition of `myMazeRows`.

Comment: Do you have the proper #include's?

Comment: It may help if you show us the declaration of `myMazeRows`.  And, as @Benoir implies, you could show us the `#include` statements as well.

Comment: Delete the parentheses after myMazeRows.  Now the compiler will see a vector, not a function.

Comment: @HansPassant , yes this worked. I was trying to set a vector object in my header file. I added a few references i was missing and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one error the Maze::GetRow() should be:

```
MazeRow*       Maze::getRow(int row)  
{ 
  return &myMazeRows.at(row);  // note the change from * to &
}
```

Another possibly is that your loop in Maze constructor is to `i<rows-1` -- most likely should be `i<rows`.  This will not cause compilation error, but runtime problems.

Answer (score 1):

As Attila said, an error can be seen at this function:

```
MazeRow *Maze::getRow(int row) 
{
    return *myMazeRows.at(row); 
}
```

If `myMazeRows` were containing a `MazeRow **`, then this would be valid, but You probably meant to take the address of the `MazeRow` object, like so:

```
MazeRow *Maze::getRow(int row) 
{
    // Ampersand (&) take the address of the row
    return &myMazeRows.at(row); 
}
```

For the `std::vector` errors, make sure you either have `using namespace std;` at the top of your header file, or are using `std::vector`, and ensure you have `#include <vector>` as well.